# How can two C# apps send messages over a WiFi Network?

Tags: c#, networking, communication, wifi

Lets say I have my C# app installed on 2 laptops connected to a WiFi Wireless Local Area Network.

How can these apps send messages to each other? What method or library can I use? I heard of using sockets but I have no idea how to work with these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) to build a communication pipe between the 2 applications. WCF encapsulates the sockets into a more manageable interface. You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you'll want to do it the same way you would in any other language. You'll open a network connection of one flavor or another (raw TCP or UDP, or a higher level protocol like HTTP) with one side acting as a server and the other acting as a client. Then each side can write data through or read data sent by the other side. It's can get pretty complicated from there. If you Google "C# Sockets" or "C# HTTP", etc, you'll find quite a few tutorials on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://royalexander.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/sending-objects-via-high-speed-asynchronous-sockets-in-c-serialization-socket-programming/) is a very good article on sending C# objects (which could include whatever messages that you want to send) over a [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) connection using the [Binary Formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx). Although it is not the most efficient, it is quite easy to grasp and get working.